# Do oranges have traces of starch?

Tags: fruit

This is for a chemistry experiment, so I just want to know if there are small traces of starch in oranges, and not whether or not I should eat an orange for its starch content, or something to that extent.

Comment: If it is related to chemistry, it would belong to **[Chemistry.SE](https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjX5-6nvP3WAhVmqVQKHXQhA2sQFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fchemistry.stackexchange.com%2F&usg=AOvVaw1m0wbDNTsBDCDDAA2Dt_NP)**

Answer (score 1):

According to [Healthy Eating](http://healthyeating.sfgate.com/carbohydrates-bananas-oranges-6659.html), oranges contain 8.98g of sugar but does not contain any starch:

> The natural sugar found in fruits doesn’t create such a big response
>   because it's balanced by the fruit's fiber content. One banana has
>   14.43 grams of sugar, compared to only 8.98 grams in an orange. The biggest difference between the two is in the amount of starch each
>   contains. The orange doesn’t have any, while the banana has 9.42 grams
>   of starch.

Comment: I’m not sure how trustworthy these websites are. [This one](https://www.livestrong.com/article/262911-a-list-of-foods-that-contain-starches/), for example, says that oranges do have starch.

Answer (score 1):

Sources are varied. [This paper studies starch in oranges](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/7867054) (I can't access full paper). However, [here authors mention that oranges contain practically no starch](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=sSF2s6OHQGMC&oi=fnd&pg=PA2&dq=oranges%20starch&ots=mxklFRouBy&sig=bMnQ6xuz-Z44Iqf0WnqunauBHhQ#v=onepage&q=oranges%20starch&f=false) (beware, images are upside down). They refer to work by

```
Stahl A.L., Maturity studies of citrus fruits, 1938
```

and quote this work saying "starch content was measured to be 0.07-0.13%" in pulp of Pineapple oranges. Compare that to [22% of potato starch](http://www.starch.dk/isi/starch/potato.asp) amount (dry mass).